# My style queue in functions.php is not working?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, wp-enqueue-scripts

I am creating a wordpress theme and my styles queue is not working.

This is the queue in functions.php

```
function style_script_enqueue(){
   wp_enqueue_style('main-styles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/main.css' );
   wp_enqueue_style('responsive-styles', get_template_directory_uri() . 
   '/css/responsive.css' );
   wp_enqueue_script('custom_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js', array(), '1.0.0', true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'style_script_enqueue');
```

I have also called wp_head(); , wp_footer(); , and checked the directory.

Comment: What is the error you are getting in console ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to enqueue your CSS/JS in a child theme derived from another existing theme? Unless you build your own theme from scratch, [child themes](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) are the preferred practice to extend existing themes (update safe).

If you are in a child theme, there are two functions you might want to consider:

- `get_template_directory()` or `get_template_directory_uri()` to refer to the parent theme path
- `get_stylesheet_directory` or `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` to refer to the child theme path

PS.: You might want to check if there are multiple functions registered for `wp_enqueue_scripts`, which try to enqueue CSS/JS with the identical name. If so, try to alter `main-styles`, `responsive-styles`, `custom_script` or the optional priority parameter for `add_action` as described in the [function documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/).

Answer (score 0):

**Its work for me.**

```
function add_css_js(){

// Load css 

wp_enqueue_style('style',get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/style.css',array(),'1.0.0','all'); 
    
//load JS

wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap',get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js',array('jquery'),'1.0.0',true);

}add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','add_css_js');
```